# Plugin Development sqlite or WordPress' database

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, sql

I am developing a plugin for WordPress that has to store between 4.5-200mb of data. I thought of using sqlite to store and access the data instead of using WP's database. From a performance perspective, would a sqlite file be better than using WP's database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there is no such thing as Wordpress Database in this context. You can use Wordpress with MySQL/MariaDB. You can use MySQL/MariaDB that wordpress uses to store your data.

The size of your data is not a problem. The performance is not so straightforward to decide. I think MySQL will come close or better in most of the time. Also you will not be able to use any wordpress Database query helper and have to build everything on your own.

If you still think that you can gain performance using SQLite and all the trouble is worth it, you first need to decide whether it's the right choice at all.

> If you need
>
> - Network access - for example accessing from another machine;
> - Any real degree of concurrency - for example, if you think you are likely to want to run several queries at once, or run a workload that has lots of selects and a few updates, and want them to go smoothly etc.
> - a lot of memory usage, for example, to buffer parts of your 1Tb database in your 32G of memory.
>
> You need to use mysql or some other server-based RDBMS.

For more details check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813890/sqlite-or-mysql-how-to-decide

Comment: Thank you. I was not clear when I said WordPress database, I really meant the database in which WP is installed. I was not sure whether using the global $wpdb object, creating a custom table and accessing it was faster than a Sqlite file. However, I believe I will use the $wpdb object and create a custom table.

Comment: The data that I will be saving will be specific to my plugin and no other plugin or software need access it.